# Eigenvalues of this matrix

Tags: matrices

What are the eigenvalues of the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}-1&0&0\\-2&0&-1\\-4&2&1\end{pmatrix}?$$
I know the characteristic polynomial is $(t+1)(t^2-t+2)$. I know the eigenvalues should be the roots of this polynomial, but $(t^2-t+2)$ has no roots, what do I do there?

Comment: @par I only want real roots

Comment: if u want only real roots then you have only $t=-1$

Comment: @RaziehNoori What is it's geometric multiplicity?

Comment: geometric multiplicity is bounded by algebraic multiplicity. thus here geometric multiplicity=1

Comment: @RaziehNoori So this matrix has a base of eigenvectors, right? But how can it only have a base of one eigenvector?

Comment: do you know diagonalizable matrices?

Comment: @RaziehNoori yes, why?

Comment: because of"So this matrix has a base of eigenvectors, right? "

Comment: when your field is $R$ your matrix isnot diagonalizable in the other words your eigenvectors doesnot make a basis

Comment: @RaziehNoori But I thought a matrix  is diagonalizable if the algebraic and geometric multiplicity of all its eigenvalues are equal, which is the case here

Answer (score 0):

$$\det\left(\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
-1 & 0 & 0\\
-2 & 0 & -1\\
-4 & 2 & 1
\end{array}\right]-tI\right)=\det\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
-1-t & 0 & 0\\
-2 & -t & -1\\
-4 & 2 & 1-t
\end{array}\right]=-t^{3}-t-2.$$

This polynomial has exactly one real root (as you noticed), and two other distinct complex roots. Unfortunately (or fortunately, depending on your perspective) there is not much you can do about that. You might want to [read this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra).

As a quick example, think about the polynomial $$x^2=-1.$$ Are there any real roots of this polynomial?

Comment: What is the geometric multiplicity of $t=-1$?

Comment: Hint: a polynomial of degree 3 can only have 3 roots.

Comment: I know that, what does that have to do with the geometric multiplicity?

Comment: @JimmyP There are three distinct eigenvalues (including the complex ones), each must have an algebraic multiplicity of at least $1$ and geometric multiplicity is bounded by algebraic multiplicity.  What does that tell you?

Comment: @Bye_World Then geom. mult. is also 1, could you look at my comment above please?